# Partial column approximation error

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling, convolution

Can someone help me understanf how to plot the next partial column in MATLAB:

[image]

while N=2001

|M|<700

ak =

[image]

Comment: actually, im trying to watch a 4 hours video just to understand the right syntax. i just need example to understand it well

Comment: If you can make a vector with all the terms under the sum, you are almost there

Comment: N=2001;
n=-700:1:700;
w0=2*pi/N;
base=(n')*n;
hezka=1j*w0*base;
PosExp=exp(hezka);
ak=((sin((199*pi/N)*n))./(N.*(sin((pi/N)*n))));
am=(1/N)*(ak*PosExp);

Comment: thats how i defined the vector. but i dont know how to plot it :(

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your code. But a ``plot(am)` or ``plot(real(am))` when   `am` is computed should work

Comment: Any more details required?

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 2001;
M = 600 ;
vectorOfK = (-M:M)';

vectorOfN = (0:N-1);
%%% For a given n
% n  = 314;

vectorOfAk = sin(199*pi*vectorOfK/2001)./(2001*sin(pi*vectorOfK/2001));
% Modify the NaN value (0/0 division) at k = 0; 
vectorOfAk(M+1) = 199/2001;

matrixOfExpo = exp(1i*2*pi/N*(vectorOfK*vectorOfN));
matrixOfAkExpoProduct = repmat(vectorOfAk,1,N).*matrixOfExpo;

vectorOfATilde = sum(matrixOfAkExpoProduct)/N;

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(vectorOfN,real(vectorOfATilde));
xlabel('Real part (index)');xlabel('Amplitude (a. u.)');

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(vectorOfN,imag(vectorOfATilde));
xlabel('Imaginary part (index)');xlabel('Amplitude (a. u.)');
```

[image]